# 12 string guitar stringing

Tags: instruments, construction, 12-string-guitar

Most commonly, 12 string guitars have their bottom four pairs arranged so that when strumming down, the octave strings sound before the original E A D and G. Is there any particular reason for this? Could they be strung the other way? Why is this the 'standard'?

Comment: My first thought was, "No, they don''t." So I had to have a closer look. Rickenbackers don't, & that's the only 12-string I've ever had. Everything else does appear to.

Comment: I truly don’t know but it seems to me that by having the high string higher  there is less of a chance of missing the second string of a pair on a downstroke than if the low string were higher. The high string might also produce a little more volume by being struck first. Just spitballing here.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it's an accuracy/volume thing - but no-one ever complained they needed to re-string their Rikki … it has a sound of its own & in all the time I had one it never even occurred to me it was the 'wrong way up'. [For the past 15 years or so my "Rikki 12" sound has been from my 6-string Variax, so it is no longer of immediate concern, tbh ;)

Comment: Ricks are not the only ones strung differently, but it is rare.

Comment: i had a 12 string takamine and that was strung octave first on the lower strings.

Comment: @bigbadmouse - I'm re-furbishing a Tanglewood right now (bridge ripped off), and that's what sparked the question. 50/50, maybe. Harking back to the '60s, my Eko 12s were as described.

Comment: i think treble upwards makes more practical sense.

Comment: @bigbadmouse - done some research, and most seem to be as you say, except Ricky, which are almost always opposite - said to produce a more jangly sound. Still confused. But looking at the nut, it's thin above thick on the Tanglewood.